# How does Thread.MemoryBarrier() flush cache?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, clr, thread-synchronization

`Thread.MemoryBarrier()` makes the program to fetch value from main memory instead of using registers, but if we have the following programs:

```
_a = xxx;
_b = xxx;
Thread.MemoryBarrier();
_c = xxx;
_d = xxx;
```

does all _a, _b, _c, _d value all fetched from main memory or only the wrapped variables _b and _c are fetched from main memory, or only _c and `_d` which after the barrier are fetched from main memory?

Comment: Where did you get this example? How are A and B called?

Comment: I would suggest staying away from memory barriers unless you really know what you are doing. Multi threading in general is difficult, but at least `lock`, `Task` etc are fairly easy to explain and reason about.