# What's the purpose of pairing MemoryBarrier in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Sample code from https://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx

```
class Foo
{
  int _answer;
  bool _complete;
 
  void A()
  {
    _answer = 123;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 1
    _complete = true;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 2
  }
 
  void B()
  {
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 3
    if (_complete)
    {
      Thread.MemoryBarrier();       // Barrier 4
      Console.WriteLine (_answer);
    }
  }
}
```

> Barriers 1 and 4 prevent this example from writing “0”. Barriers 2 and 3 provide a freshness guarantee: they ensure that if B ran after A, reading _complete would evaluate to true.

I get the point that the purpose of `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` is to provide a full memory barrier so that the code above it and the code below it won't jump across, but what does Barrier 2 do here? there is no code after Barrier 2, why the author still use a barrier to stop no existing code jumping above the barrier? how does Barriers 2 and 3  pair work together to provide a freshness guarantee?

Comment: Related: [Why using multiple Thread.MemoryBarrier() calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77356832/why-using-multiple-thread-memorybarrier-calls)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias the question has been modified to focus on the caching part, this question is about why using pair of memory barrier

Comment: Previous answer (Asked 9 years, 8 months ago)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652938/where-to-places-fences-memory-barriers-to-guarantee-a-fresh-read-committed-write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barrier 2 is included to make sure any future code changes won't accidentally introduce ordering issues.  In particular, it forces the write to be flushed to main memory immediately.

Comment: is it that easy?  but the author said "Barriers 2 and 3 provide a freshness guarantee", how does this pair work together especially they are in different method?

Comment: do you mean Barrier 1 is mainly for fence purpose while Barrier 2 is for flushing cache purpose?

Comment: yes its that easy. But you need to know why...

If it's placed after a write, then it forces the write to be flushed to main memory immediately.

If it's place before a read, is its guarantees a fresh read.